# & in procedure parameter - Purpose of "&"?

Tags: vba

What is the purpose of "&" in `1&` in the following procedure call?

```
   sndPlaySound32(WhatSound, 1&)
```

Answer (score 8):

It tells the compiler the second parameter is a `long` and not just an `int`.

This is needed for cases where the host language doesn't have an explicit knowledge of the API or the call isn't declared manually so that type-conversion can happen properly.

The full list of [sigil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29)s that can be used include the following; generally `@` and `$` aren't used for API calls.

- `@` = Decimal
- `#` = Double (8 bytes)
- `%` = Integer (2 bytes)
- `&` = Long (4 bytes)
- `!` = Single (4 bytes)
- `$` = String

Answer (score 1):

The use of such type specifiers is deprecated, but for the record these are the different variable types:

`& Long`
`% Integer`
`# Double`
`! Single`
`@ Decimal`
`$ String`